# Invalid value for field 'resource.managed.domains[0]

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create flytime-google-cert --domains=flytime.io,api.flytime.io,socket.flytime.io --global
```

Above commands give the error of

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssl-certificates.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value for field 'resource.managed.domains[0]': 'flytime.io api.flytime.io socket.flytime.io'. Invalid domain name specified.
```

What's the wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you put it inside the quote:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create flytime-google-cert --domains="flytime.io,api.flytime.io,socket.flytime.io" --global
```